# Plugin installation on TeamCity

Tags: c#, teamcity

according to the documentation, installation for [tcWebhooks](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tcplugins/wiki/TcWebHooks) is as follows

> Download the jar file.  Locate the plugins directory for your TeamCity
>   install. This is normally $HOME/.BuildServer/plugins/.  Create a new
>   directory (folder) inside the plugins directory called "tcWebHooks"
>   (it can be named whatever you want).  Copy the jar you downloaded into
>   the tcWebHooks directory.  Restart TeamCity.

TeamCity Professional 7.1.4 (build 24331) didn't create a .BuildServer folder and I cannot find that anywhere on my machine.  Does anyone know the default path for the installation of plugins? I see there is a plugins folder at "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins" which contains a lot of plugins but following the above instructions still doesn't seem to pick up the plugin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should put your plug-ins into server. They will be deployed to agents automatically.

Just copy the zip file of the plugin into the plugins folder in the teamcity data folder, which by default is `C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\Teamcity\plugins`.

If you are not sure you can find it under administration > global settings

Comment: Correct, the documentation is wrong for the tcWebhooks plugin!

Comment: It was correct for older version of TC/WinServer. For TC7 and W2008R2 it is not.

Comment: If i copy that location, is it possible to reload it without restarting teamcity? @AlešRoubíček